# Get a list of object with max values

Tags: java, java-stream

I have to get the list of objects containing the max value. The comparator max in Java 8 returns only one object.

To do this I had to stream twice the list:

```
 OptionalInt max = students.stream()
            .mapToInt(student -> student.getAssignedProjects().size())
            .max();

    return this.students.stream()
            .filter(student -> student.getAssignedProjects().size() == max.getAsInt())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This solution works. I think there is a better way to solve this but I ca not figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you want a single pipeline, you can group the `Student`s by that property, and if you produce a `TreeMap` for the output, it will be sorted, so you'll have access to the `Set` corresponding with the max value:

```
return
this.students()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(student -> student.getAssignedProjects().size(),
             TreeMap::new,
             Collectors.toSet()))
    .lastEntry()
    .getValue();
```

Of course, if the number of `Student`s having the max value is small relative to the size of the input list, it would be inefficient to sort the grouped `Student`s (which is what creating a `TreeMap` would do). Your original code would be more efficient.

Comment: Any chance to use `Collectors.maxBy` here? I tried to find a different *single pipeline* without success so far.

Comment: @deHaar I believe `maxBy` would return a single element (having the max value), so it doesn't fit the OP's requirements.

Comment: I know, that's why I didn't succeed using it... It cannot be used along with `Collectors.toList()` or similar. I thought there might be a way...